# how to save the return value of multiply process in the background in bash?

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to save the return value of each process in the background that running in parallel and ends in difference times.

For example (here the return value is in all process is 0 but in my script will be many returns values):

```
    #!/bin/bash
    echo "" > empty.txt
    (sleep 4 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 3 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 12 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 9 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 7 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 6 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
    (sleep 4 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> empty.txt ) &
```

but here I dont know each process what his return value (I just get them all in a file)

Can I use `mkfifo` for fixing the problem? each process will have an number by the time he get into the fifo and his return value will be bound to the order of first in first out.

I tried like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkfifo pipe1
(sleep 4 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
(sleep 6 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
(sleep 9 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
(sleep 2 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
(sleep 12 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
(sleep 4 ; echo "my return value is $? " >> $pipe1 ) &
```

but it is not working. maybe I'm not working with fifo right?

Comment: "Not working" is about as vague as it comes. How are you reading from the FIFO? How are you preventing it from closing as soon as the first writer exits?

Comment: I'm not sure, I just dont know to use the mkfifo..

Comment: Which is fine -- mkfifo isn't the right tool for this job.

Comment: (Now, if your question were "why doesn't mkfifo work the way I expect?", that would be a different question, with a different answer; feel free to ask it... separately).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your outputs are short enough to fit inside a single write call (to avoid interleaving):

```
for ((x=0; x<10; x++)); do
  (sleep $((RANDOM % 10)); echo "My number is $x and my return value is $?") &
done >output.txt
```

If that's not safe enough, you can lock:

```
for ((x=0; x<10; x++)); do
  (sleep $((RANDOM % 10))
   retval=$?
   exec {lock_fd}>.output_lock                        # open the lockfile
   flock -x "$lock_fd"                                # grab the lock
   echo "My number is $x; my return value is $retval" # do the write
  ) &                                                 # lock released by subshell exit
done >output.txt
```

...replacing `.output_lock` with a filename of a lockfile you want to use to coordinate.

---

Note that `{lock_fd}>.output_lock` is syntax that requires bash 4.1 or newer; for older shells, you'll need to assign an FD number yourself -- for instance, `3>.output_lock` -- and use that number when calling `flock` later.

---

You could also avoid the entire matter of locking by calling `wait` on each child process in turn (with its PID) to collect their exit status values from the parent.

That is:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a pids=( )
for ((x=0; x<10; x++)); do
  sleep $((RANDOM % 10)) &
  pids[$x]=$!
done

for pid in "${!pids[@]}"; do
  wait "$pid"
  echo "Child with PID $pid exited with status $?"
done >output.txt
```

The disadvantage of this is that you won't get output immediately as jobs exit -- instead, feedback will be given in process-id order, even if the jobs exit in a different order.

---

Another approach, of course, is to write each job's exit status to a different file.

```
for ((x=0; x<10; x++)); do
  (sleep $((RANDOM % 10)); echo "My number is $x and my return value is $?" >"output.$x.txt") &
done
```

Comment: Thank you! but, In your second solution, Dont you lose the return value of a process if other process finished before him and we wait "pid" to the longest process ?

Comment: No return values are lost. Jobs stay in the process table until they're waited for -- that's what zombies are.

Comment: (which means that there _will_ be some zombies floating around if jobs finish out-of-order here, but they're harmless but for aesthetics).

Comment: Thank you again!! but when im runng your second solution i get this error:-IN LINE 10 -pid 10 is not a child of this shell

Comment: Also in the output file I get that the return value of each command is 127, it should be 0..

Comment: Simple thinko: `wait "$x"` needs to be `wait "$pid"`.